# Should we declare a collection class or interface?

Tags: c#, collections, interface

I've got this idea from Java - i was told that you should declare a collection like this

```
List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

where `ArrayList` is a class implementing `List` interface. The point of this is to enhance maintainability by generalizing code - as, should you change teh implementation to, e.g `LinkedList<Object>`, you could to it 100% painlessly.

So, projecting this on C#, is it considered a good practice to do the same thing in C# :

```
IList<Object> list = new List<Object>()
```

?

EDIT : i just found that LinkedList in C# does not even implement the IList interface, so i guess it settles the question for lists at least

Comment: it depends on what you need. we can't answer it for you.

Comment: Basically it´s almost allways a good idea to develop against interfaces, however there´s no general rule to do so, it also depends on what you´re trying to achieve and what your preferences are.

Comment: The question should be, do you need that extra maintainability?

Comment: First, why an object?  Are you trying to always get the same type or are you have an overload so you are getting different objects?  Interface are better if you are returning  different types.  If you are always returning same type it probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, generally this is a good practice to use interfaces wherever you can.

There are two important exceptions for containers, though:

- When you must use a hash-based container for objects that are not comparable, use `HashSet<T>` or `Dictionary<TK,TV>`,
- When you declare a local variable, using `var` for implicit typing is often preferred for convenience,

Note that if you plan to use a sorted container you have `IOrderedSet<T>` and `IOrderedDictionary<TK,TV>`.